# Check if a cell from a google sheet has a hyperlink inserted

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I want my code to check the cell values from a column and pick only the rows that contains hyperlinks. The function has_hyperlink works with a local stored excel file, but when I try to use it on the google sheet I get the error AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'hyperlink'. This is the code that I used and here is a link of what the google sheet looks like [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uZGMAT8cEt_A_TzzF5jHPLVIK7yzVomobkCQKFu3P4Q/edit?usp=sharing). Thank you for your help!

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def has_hyperlink(cell):
    """
    Check if a cell has a hyperlink.
    """
    if 'hyperlink' in cell:
        return True
    return False

# Set up credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path/to/your/credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Open the Google Sheet by title
spreadsheet = gc.open('Your Google Sheet Title')

# Select the worksheet (e.g., the first sheet)
worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1

# Specify the cell you want to check (e.g., B2)
cell_to_check = worksheet.cell(2, 2)

# Check if the cell has a hyperlink
if has_hyperlink(cell_to_check._properties):
    print(f"The cell B2 has a hyperlink: {cell_to_check.hyperlink}")
else:
    print("The cell B2 does not have a hyperlink")
```

If you may help me just with the check of the hyperlinks, it would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check whether a cell has the hyperlink using gspread with Python.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def has_hyperlink(obj, cell):
    """
    Check if a cell has a hyperlink.
    """
    r, c = gspread.utils.a1_to_rowcol(cell)
    o = obj["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"][r - 1].get("values", [])[c - 1]
    if 'hyperlink' in o:
        return True
    return False


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path/to/your/credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet = gc.open('Your Google Sheet Title')
worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1

service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=gc.auth)
obj = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet.id, fields="sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink,formattedValue))))", ranges=[worksheet.title]).execute()

cell1 = "A2"
res1 = has_hyperlink(obj, cell1)
print(res1)

cell2 = "B2"
res2 = has_hyperlink(obj, cell2)
print(res2)
```

- In this modification, the hyperlinks are checked using [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). In order to use this method, [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) is used with the gspread client.
- When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, `True` and `False` are shown as the output values.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: As OP is using coordinates to scan across the sheet (instead of cell names), perhaps you might want to include a utility function that converts indexes to string, such as `coords_to_cell_name = lambda i, j: string.ascii_uppercase[i-1] + str(j)`? (Using the `string` core library). Then `cell1 = coords_to_cell_name(2,2)`, et cetera

Comment: @soyapencil Thank you for your comment. If the row and column numbers instead of a1Notation are used, `r` and `c` of `r, c = gspread.utils.a1_to_rowcol(cell)` can be replaced with them in my proposed script. For example, if `2, 2` of cell "B2" is used, `r, c = gspread.utils.a1_to_rowcol(cell)` can be modified to `r, c, = 2, 2`. If I misunderstood your comment, I apologize.